# How do I turn off auto-parenthesis generation in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, parentheses

When typing a function name (or auto completing) IDEA automatically puts the parentheses after it and puts the cursor between them:
foo(|)

I greatly dislike this and would much prefer it let me type the parentheses myself. Is there any way to do this?

Update:

Re: "Insert Pair Bracket" setting:

So, this option is turned off already for me. I just tested and found out that this ONLY happens in Actionscript files. In Java it only gives me the ( character and it lets my type over it. In Actionscript it automatically puts both parens no matter what I do. Might have to look deeper into the plugin.

Comment: There are two separate issues here: 1. How to disable automatic generation of opening and closing parentheses in actionscript, (there appears to be an option but it does not work for actionscript,) and 2. How to disable automatic generation of opening parenthesis in java. (There appears to be *no option whatsoever* for this one.)

Answer (score 39):

Disable **Insert pair bracket**:

[image: Insert pair bracket]

Comment: So, this option is turned off already for me. I just tested and found out that this ONLY happens in Actionscript files. In Java it only gives me the ( character and it lets my type over it. In Actionscript it automatically puts both parens no matter what I do. Might have to look deeper into the plugin. :( Thanks though!

Comment: Yeah, I turned that off too. Still seeing brackets inserted "for" me in Webstorm 6 in a js file

Comment: Preferences > Editor > General > Smart Keys > Insert pair bracket

Comment: This doesn't work for JavaScript in Webstorm 2017.1. Everytime I want to pass a function typed with autocompletion instead of calling it I still need to remove the brackets. The only workaround I found so far is to finish autocompletion with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` ([Complete Current Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10481803/506695)) but want it to be the default behavior for autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also but I found the magical switch to disable it.  Within Intellij settings, go to:  Settings->Clojure (For current project) and you will see a setting checked called:  "Use structural editing".  Just un-check this option checkbox and you will not have auto-closing paren for a new open paren.

Jeff

Comment: This is what Google scraped as the correct answer for this question, although it is specific to the Clojure plugin and not universal to IntelliJ.