# Jquery sortable table shrinks while dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

My problem is that table shrinks while dragging. Row remains it's width, but table shrinks. Is there a way to keep table's original width while dragging?

[Example is here](https://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/WMZmVj/)

Sortable functionality is being called with:

```
 $("table[id=tblSelectedCAMERC] tbody").sortable();
```

[image]

Comment: I had same problem in my project. For getting ride of this, maybe following link help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146000/jqueryui-sortable-on-table-rows-shrinks-them-while-being-dragged.

Comment: It's not the problem of rows shrinking, but whole table shrinks. Row stays same width.

Comment: If you inspect in selected row, you can see when it is dragged, it's style is changed and this style causes shrink row not table.

Comment: Perhaps you any solution? Can I ask you to modify code? I've examined selected row and there is really jquery ui class appended. But I don't know how to prevent table from shrinking.

Comment: I suspect this is related to the `items` option or the `placeholder`.

Answer (score 1):

When using Sortable for a `<table>` element, it is sometimes best to define exactly what will be the `item`. Please review: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items

I would advise the following:

```
$(function(){  
  $("table[id=tblSelectedCAMERC] tbody").sortable({
    sort: function(evt, ui){
      debugger;
    },
    item: "> tr",
    handle: ".iORAS_ORD"
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

**Update**

As there are some extra cells, You can do this:

**CSS**

```
.shrink td:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){  
  $("table[id=tblSelectedCAMERC] tbody").sortable({
    sort: function(evt, ui){
      debugger;
    },
    items: "> tr",
    handle: ".iORAS_ORD",
    scroll: true,
    tolerance: "intersect",
    placeholder: "shrink"
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

Remember that the placeholder class is applied to the item, in this case the `<tr>`. So if we need to suppress or hide some of the cells, we need to select them. This example assumes 1 extra cell. If you have more cells, I would advise adding a class to them (E.G.: `hidden`) so that you can more easily select them. You could also try other CSS selectors (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: The table still shrinks while dragging. Example is here: https://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/WMZmVj/

Comment: @FrenkyB your placeholder somehow has 7 extra cells (`<td>` elements) for it's row; hence, the other rows "shrink". You could add a class via `placeholder` and define it there. Also `forcePlaceholderSize` can be helpful.

Comment: I've deleted extra cells (with display:none) and that solved the problem. Although I don't understand how to keep those hidden cells and not shrinking table? Please add this to your answer so I can mark it as solution.

Comment: @FrenkyB change their width to 0.

Comment: I've tried with {width:0;display:none;} - https://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/oEqMRo Problem is that as soon as I use display:none, table shrinks. But with only width:0, columns are visible. Basically I have to hide column, but without using display:none. Any more ideas how to do it?

Comment: @FrenkyB I still see 1 extra cell on the end. Adding update.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your style sheet:

```
.ui-sortable-helper {
  display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sortable function, add a self-created placeholder **where you define the column span of the table**. In my case `8`:

```js
start: function(even, ui) { ui.placeholder.html('<!--[if IE]><td colspan="8" >&nbsp;</td><![endif]-->')},
```

Now there is an empty row, without height. So add the height in your css (or any other desired layout):

```css
.ui-sortable-helper, .sortable-placeholder {
    display: table; /* This, for me, shows a border around where the row is placed */
    height: 50px;
}
```

To understand what's happening; jquery creates an element to show in the ui. Various reasons for the ui to mess up, especially in a table. If you create your own placeholder (it could be pink too, for example) you can define how to not mess it up. In this case, adding the colspan.