# Can IntelliJ IDEA automatically format a code block after finishing it?

Tags: intellij-idea, autoformatting

Some IDEs offer the feature to automatically format a line or block of code after finishing it   e.g. by writing the closing curly or semicolon.
I find it hard to believe that IDEA does not offer this kind of feature. Or does it?

If you know how to turn it on - or if I maybe need some plugin - let me and the world know, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic reformat feature, related requests:

- [IDEABKL-5806](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5806) Automatically trigger code formatter on file save
- [IDEABKL-475](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-475) Hard (auto-)reformat code

See also [my answer to the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10481803/104891) with the `Complete Current Statement` workaround.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a single line, you can use the `Complete Current Statement` action (which adds a closing bracket, semi-colon, and so on) with <kbd>ctrl-shift-enter</kbd> - this seems to reformat the whole line.

Otherwise, you can obviously rebind ctrl-w and ctrl-alt-l (to reformat selected text) or just ctrl-alt-l (reformat whole file) to faster / easier keybindings so that you can quickly reformat whenever you want to.