# Force auto format in Android Studio (Intellij)

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, autoformatting, autoformat

Is possible to make that Intellij auto format my code while I'm writing it (without using any shortcut) ?

I have seen this question was done 3 years ago ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20631357/1081827)) and the answer was that it will be implemented in the future and I'm looking for this feature but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible to make that Intellij auto format my code while I'm
>   writing it (without using any shortcut) ?

**No,** it is not possible for now.

From your question i was wondering if this is possible or not but **at the end after searching i found no way
to do this**. It just shows shortcuts to format code and nothing else.