# How to jump out of brackets in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Does IntelliJ have the ability to tab out of auto-completed brackets? As in, when you press "tab" key near a closing bracket, the cursor will jump over it instead of adding a new tab. This is a pretty standard feature in Eclipse. In IntelliJ IDEA you must use arrow keys to do so.

Similar question was asked 4 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481679/how-to-move-out-of-auto-completed-brackets-in-intellij-idea-without-using-the-a), but maybe 4 year isn't enough time to complete this complex feature, so I'm asking again.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6984 As you can see here, no change at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

Initial implementation for this feature is available starting from IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 version. It works more like in MS Visual Studio - without visual indication of tab 'exit' position. For now, it should work in Java, SQL, Python and some other files. It will take some time for other languages to catch up - some language-specific code changes are required. The feature is disabled by default, you can enable it in:

`Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac)| `Editor` | `General` | `Smart Keys` | **Jump outside closing bracket/quote with Tab**.

---

Original answer:

Nothing new since the original question was submitted, except [a third-party plug-in](https://github.com/rgolangh/idea-braces-plugin) that was started by one of the users.

For some reason the author didn't release a binary version of the plug-in yet.

I went ahead and built the plug-in, you can [get the jar file here](ftp://ftp.intellij.net/pub/.idea/editor.jar).

Copy it into the IDE [plugins folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519), restart IDEA and use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Keyboard shortcut can be changed in the Keymap settings:

[image: shortcut]

Feature requests and bug reports [should go here](https://github.com/rgolangh/idea-braces-plugin/issues).

Comment: The jar file can no longer be accessed. The of this missing feature hasn't been fixed in a build yet.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this after searching for something similar. In case you're still looking, I wrote a plugin for Intellij that you might want to check out. Download it here: https://github.com/namarino41/intellij-tab-out.

Comment: @namarino this feature is now available out of the box, I've updated the answer.

Comment: At my company we've migrated from eclipse to idea and to ease the transition we're  using the eclipse code formatter plugin for intellij.  One of our formatting options is that we pad parentheses with a space. E.g. `methodInvocation( param1, param 2 );`.  It appears that when using this combination of the eclipse code formatter, and this formatting style, tab to jump out doesn't work.  Has anyone come across this or have a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Just type in the closing bracket again, it will get you out of the bracket.

For example if you are typing "Sandeep", as soon as you enter ".. it will be like ""... then you enter rest of the text "sandeep".. and at the end type " again... it will take you out of the double quotes.

I have demonstrated above for double quotes , you can do the same for any brackets.

Comment: It acually works