# Is there a way in IntelliJ to quickly add a ";" to the end of the current line?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, when you are editing a class, and start typing

```
someMethod
```

then Intellij suggests

```
someMethod( ... );
```

It allows you to fill in the parameters, but "most importantly" (for my question): it already puts the ";" char at the end of the line. So after I provided the parameter values, the line is complete, and compiles.

But when I type other expressions, like this:

```
Object o = new Str
```

Again, I get a suggestion, like

```
new String( original: "" )
```

Meaning: the IDE tells me that there is a parameter *original*, and the cursor is placed between two quotes. But: for these situations, there is **no** closing ";"!

So, each time, I need to use some navigation keys (like *command right arrow* on my mac keyboard), to first move the cursor to the end of the line, to then type ";" myself.

Instead: I would like to have a single key-stroke, to be used *anywhere* in an expression, that makes IntelliJ **add** a trailing ";" to the current line.

Is that possible with IntelliJ, if so: how?

Comment: control-enter ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10481803/104891 and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#statements_completion.

Comment: @vikingsteve On Mac, "control enter" means " opens the *generate* menu. "option enter" (which you probably meant) opens the window to fix compiler problems. But there is no entry "add a single ;" in there, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ Idea lets you record macros and play them back when a keyboard shortcut is pressed. You could try that?

The macro that you'd want to record would be something along the lines of `END + ;` (or the mac equivalent)

[Using Macros in the Editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html)

Comment: Question got closed, and your answer is answering it (although the duplicate works better). Thanks, anyway ... and welcome to upvote level ;-)