# How to move out of auto-completed HTML tag in IntelliJ IDEA (without using the arrow keys)?

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

The premise is similar to this question: [How to move out of auto-completed brackets in IntelliJ IDEA (without using the arrow keys)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10481679), but the suggested answer <kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work for HTML tags. Instead, it autocompletes a new tag.

I would like to move out of the current tag I'm in to the next level up without using the mouse or cursor keys.

E.g. I've come to the end of my HTML tag content:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some <span>arbitrary|</span></li>
</ul>
```

and I would like to jump outside of the `span`:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some <span>arbitrary</span>|</li>
</ul>
```

Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> autocompletes a new tag:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some <span><arbitrary>|</arbitrary></span></li>
</ul>
```

Is there some way of doing this in any version of IntelliJ? <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> both jump to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Navigate > Next Edit Emmet Point** (`Alt+Shift+]` in default keymap) to jump from

```
  <li>Some <span>arbitrary|</span></li>
```

to

```
 <li>Some <span>arbitrary</span>|</li>
```

Comment: Interesting. It works in this specific example, but when there's white space (e.g. from `...</span>|</li>\n</ul>`, it jumps to after the `</ul>`. Not what I expected; I'll have to read into Emmet.

Comment: So it jumps to the next point one can apply an Emmet template. Unfortunately it's not ideal because of the rules involved. If for whatever reason I have some mismatched tags (happens often), e.g. `<td><pre><code>Content|</code></td>`, the next Emmet Point is usually where the next `<code>` tag is. Thank you anyway, definitely better than nothing.